# why throw an oracle exception "ORA-00972: identifier is too long" in my java web project

Tags: java, oracle, servlets, web

The problem is when i call the function `importDBfromAllSheets.insertTables();` in my servlet, it will throw the `"ORA-00972: identifier is too long"`.

But when i call the function in local main() function, it works well.

servlet code:

```
if (username != null && username.equals(GlobalVariables.defaultUserName)
            && password != null && password.equals(GlobalVariables.defaultPassword)) {
        ImportDBfromAllSheets importDBfromAllSheets = new ImportDBfromAllSheets(
                GlobalVariables.oracleUrl, GlobalVariables.oracleUserName, GlobalVariables.oraclePassword);
        importDBfromAllSheets.insertTables();
        System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaa");
        response.getWriter().print("Updating...");
    } else {
        response.getWriter().print("User/Pwd error");
    }
```

and main() code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ImportDBfromAllSheets importDBfromAllSheets = new ImportDBfromAllSheets(
            GlobalVariables.oracleUrl, GlobalVariables.oracleUserName, GlobalVariables.oraclePassword);
    importDBfromAllSheets.insertTables();
}
```

and my insertTables() is about:

```
StringBuilder insert_sql = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder subSql1 = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder subSql2 = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> columnNames = getColumnNames();
    for (String columnName : columnNames) {
        subSql1.append("\"").append(columnName).append("\",");
        subSql2.append("?,");
    }
    String substring = subSql1.substring(0, subSql1.length() - 1);
    String substring2 = subSql2.substring(0, subSql2.length() - 1);
    insert_sql.append("insert into \"Complaints-All\" (")
            .append(substring).append(") values (").append(substring2).append(")");
    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(insert_sql.toString());
        for (List<String> row : rows.subList(1, rows.size())) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.size(); j++) {
                if (row.get(j).isEmpty())
                    pst.setNull(j + 1, Types.VARCHAR);
                else
                    pst.setString(j + 1, row.get(j));
            }
            pst.addBatch();
        }
        pst.executeBatch();
        con.commit();
        System.out.println("Complaints-All: insert success!");
        fileRename(path);
```

the exception is "pst.executeBatch();" threw.

It is strange that when i check the table in PL/SQL, it works well after i do main() function.

this is my sql:

```
insert into "Complaints-All" ("PR ID","Product","GE Knowledge Date","Comply code","Hazard.","Hazard - Lower Level.","Hazardous Situation.","SPCR Root Cause Code","Hazardous or Potentially Haz?","Regulatory Non-Compliance?","Modality Segment","Modality","Product Name","Product Line","Complaint Closure Code","Customer Country","RAC Product Line","RAC Product Name","SPC - System/Component Code","SPC - Problem Code","SPC - Correction Code","Further Investigation/Actions?","Additional Reportability Info","Subsystem","Symptom Code","Problem Code","Investigation Code","Division","PR State (AKA “State”)","Date Created","Date Closed","Device Identification Number","Complaint / Inv / CAPA Link","Customer's Issue Description","FE's Issue Desc (Editable)","Actions Taken/Rep's (Editable)","Closure Summary","Comments","Additional Info Requested","Parts Used","Software Version","Manufacturing Site","Model Number","SPCR Symptom Description","SPCR Problem Description","SPCR Resolution") select '10000143','Proteus','2012-11-30','','','','','','No','No','RAD','X-Ray','PROTEUS','PROTEUS XR/A','Low impact - Further Investigation not required','USA','','','XP','E1','PZ','No Further Investigation Needed (Investigation is','This complaint is not a hazardous situation, nor is it expected to result in harm to a patient, operator or other user. In accordance with GEHC Post Market Procedures, regulatory reporting for this event is not required because this event: 1) Did not result in a death. 2) Does not represent a serious threat to public health. 3) Did not result in a serious injury, serious illness, serious deterioration in the state of health or other serious harm. 4) The potential for death or serious injury to result from reoccurrence is considered to be remote based on the analysis above. 5) Has not led to a corrective action to prevent death or serious injury. 6) Did not involve a counterfeit product. 7) Did not cause fetal risk or result in congenital abnormality or birth defect. 8) Did not result in an accidental radiation occurrence nor was a Notification of Defect/Failure to Comply.','','','','','Diagnostic Imaging (DI)','Low Impact - Closed','2012-12-19','2012-12-22','706632PRO','','console display blank','12/19/2012 03:13 AM (GMT) added by TrackwiseService Production (PID-000006): console display blank ','12/19/2012 03:13 AM (GMT) added by TrackwiseService Production (PID-000006): 005~msa maintenance   ~MODEL#                    ~SERIAL#               ~PATIENT IMPACT ====> no patient involved.               ~DIAGNOSIS/TROUBLESHOOTING ====> ac/dc fuse defective. defective lvps.               ~REPAIR/CALIBRATION ====> replaced fuse and lsps brd.performed a reboot. system bootedup successfully. performed a test acquisition. acquisition  successfully completed. ','','','','2348721|5126988-2|99185290','','GE Hangwei Medical Systems Co','','','','' from dual where not exists(select "PR ID" from "Complaints-All" where ("PR ID"='10000143'))
```

There is no error after I execute this sql in PL/SQL, but also throw exception in java `"java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long"`.

Comment: Print the generated SQL statement (the content of `insert_sql`) and post it here.

Comment: Show your ddl please.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*I execute this sql in PL/SQL*" can you show us the stored procedure where you use this? And in which line exactly is the exception thrown?

Comment: could be a charset issue. Maybe some symbol correctly represented in a Java String become two symbol when passed to Oracle due to conversion to the charset encoding Oracle is using.

Comment: @Jens: that's not what "identifier is too long" means.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  the exception is thrown in "rs = stmt.executeQuery(insert_sql.toString());" my question is to say this error is only occured in servlet,  there is no error when I test it in a main().

Comment: That line is not part of the code you posted. And you should **not** use `executeQuery()` to run an `insert` statement. And what about your stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess.

Check your `insert_sql.toString()`. Looks like you have some extra " char before the column name or in the mid of the name so DB includes in the column name all the text after. Or opposite you miss closing " char.

Like `insert into my_table ("my column), values ("aaaa");`

Comment: "Complaints-All: update success!
Process finished with exit code 0" in my main() function return, so, i think the insertTables() is works and the insert_sql is right when i copy it to PL/SQL and execute.